# When bulk uploading products via csv

Tags: magento-1.9, upload

When bulk uploading products via csv, do the columns need to be in a specific order or having the correct column name is good enough?

Answer (score 1):

No you don't need to worry about column order. You need to specify proper column name to import product.

For proper name you can just export 1 product and use that name for column to specify proper attributes.

Answer (score 1):

It depends how you are importing bulk products.

If you are using dataflow profiles to import products, then there is an option under **data format tab** i.e **Original Magento attribute names in first row:** Select yes if you are importing with attribute name in first row. ANd if you are selecting it as no, then you have to maintain the order of columns.